# Tabledit not sending post action

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tabledit

I recently inserted the tabledit in a page, I followed several examples but with all the plugin does not post, does not post anything is all empty, I do not know how to make the post work you can give me a hand?

Simple script:

```
     <table class='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  $('.table').Tabledit({
    url: 'index.php',
    columns: {
      identifier: [0, 'id'],
      editable: [
        [1, 'col1'],
        [2, 'col2'],
        [3, 'col3']
      ]
    }
  });
</script>
```

Everything is simple it works I receive the buttons but to save and to delete the post in ajax but without fields without the formdata, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You're only missing the handlers declaration in your Tabledit definition.

There are examples in the [documentation](https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/#examples).

I've added them for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.table').Tabledit({
        url: 'index.php',
        columns: {
            identifier: [0, 'Id'],
            editable: [
                [1, 'Firstname'],
                [2, 'Lastname'],
                [3, 'Email']
            ]
        },
        onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // deal with success there
        },
        onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // deal with errors there
        },
        onAjax: function(action, serialize) {
            // open your xhr here 
            console.log("on Ajax");
            console.log("action : ", action);
            console.log("data : ", serialize);
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-tabledit@1.0.0/jquery.tabledit.min.js"></script>
<table class='table'>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>Firstname</th>
         <th>Lastname</th>
         <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>Doe</td>
         <td>Doe</td>
         <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: exactly is what started me to the small victory thanks to your support and your javascript you saved me from a black weekend was wrong the .js file I do not know how and also the script in the source ... thank you so much the study. thank you again

Comment: Sorry but ... I do not understand but there is a check not to use the script in offline .. it only works if I use the online version if I try to put it in localhost does not post, is it only usable online?

Comment: if I try to copy the external source
<script src = 'https: //cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-tabledit@1.0.0/jquery.tabledit.min.js'>
in localhost
<script src = 'localhost / script / jquery.tabledit.min.js'>
  I propose the same problem that is not working the post ..
is it possible that there is a lock I can not see?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm messed up by myself
it eliminates everything I've said
thank you very much again

Answer (score 1):

Just return true when onAjax is called

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   
 $('.table').Tabledit({
        url: 'index.php',
        columns: {
            identifier: [0, 'Id'],
            editable: [
                [1, 'Firstname'],
                [2, 'Lastname'],
                [3, 'Email']
            ]
        },
        onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // deal with success there
        },
        onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // deal with errors there
        },
        onAjax: function(action, serialize) {
            // open your xhr here 
            console.log("on Ajax");
            console.log("action : ", action);
            console.log("data : ", serialize);
            return serialize;
            **return serialize;**
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some code to your concerned cells:

```
<td class='tabledit-view-mode' style='cursor: pointer; background-color: #DEE1E8;'>
<span class='tabledit-span' style='display: inline;'>YOUR CELL DATA</span>
<input name='VAR_NAME' disabled='' class='tabledit-input form-control input-sm' style='display: none;' type='text' value='YOUR CELL DATA'></td>
```

Tabledit will change the display to input when you click on it and that way you'll have your variables.

Comment: I assure you that it works even without html input type text, it generates it automatically.
Thank you for your answer was very generous